# How to convert a child instance to parent class and the reverse in PHP?

Tags: php, class

```
$child_instance = (childClass)$parent_instance;
$parent_instance = (parentClass)$child_instance;
```

Or is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I am pretty new to OOP in PHP too, and hence, had spent like an hour to look for a way to convert a child class instance to a parent class instance.

Alas, found it!

In your child class, just have this method:

```
function loadChildWithParent($instanceOfParent) {
        $props = get_object_vars($instanceOfParent);
        foreach ($props as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
}
```

And in your parent class, you can just call this method via:

```
$objNew = new student();
$objNew->voidLoadStudent($this);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. After you use `new ClassA` you cannot change the type of class the class of that object.

Comment: what do you mean with this?